# Since upgrading to 2.78 requires rekey objects that were not even moved when doing animation.

Tags: animation

I upgraded to 2.78 and 2.78a. Since doing so every time I keyframe an object, let's say the left foot after moving it to position, if I don't also re-key the right foot even though it wasn't moved it will move when the left foot moves. Having to rekey objects that are not to be moved in the first place has had me pulling my hair out. Any suggestions on why this is happening? Is it a bug?

Comment: I couldn't recreate the problem in my files. Could you provide your .blend?

Comment: No I am making a complete animation. All I am doing is changing the position of the char's feet. If I move the left foot and key it then move the frames forward some for the right foot's next position and key that, during the scroll through the left leg moves when it shouldn't. My only work around so far is to rekey the left foot position when I get the right foot where I want it. It never did that before.

Comment: I wish I could help, but I don't get anything similar with my/rigify rigs and characters.Sorry.

Comment: Can you make a stick figure and see if you can recreate the situation, upload that Blender file - we might be able to help.  If you can't recreate the problem, your left and right foot might be linked somehow, i.e. when you do anything to one foot's Dope sheet strip, it's affecting the other's.